# Sftp upload from memory stream asp.net

Tags: asp.net, memorystream

I am trying to upload a csv file that is created from a query and upload via sftp.
I am trying to avoid creating a file and then reading the file to upload it by keeping the data in memory.

Thanks in advance

```
var customerAddresses = addresses.Select(p => new { p.Customer.Name, p.Customer.AlternateName, p.City, p.StateProvince });
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  //if you pass a file path to streamWriter it creates a csv with the correct format and data
  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter()) 
  {
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
      csv.WriteRecords(customerAddresses);
      var fileName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(dateFromat) + destinationFileName;
      var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyLocation);

      var connectionInfo = new PrivateKeyConnectionInfo(address,
         username,
         new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyLocation)
      );
    
      memoryStream.Flush();
      using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
      {
         client.Connect();
         client.ChangeDirectory(serverDirectory);
         client.UploadFile(memoryStream, fileName); //is always an empty file
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setting `memoryStream` Position to beginning with `Seek` before calling `UploadFile` and calling `streamWriter.Flush();`, not `memoryStream.Flush()`:

```
      streamWriter.Flush();
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
      {
         client.Connect();
         client.ChangeDirectory(serverDirectory);
         client.UploadFile(memoryStream, fileName);
      }
```

Comment: The suggested changes did not fix the issue. I edit the code to read an existing file using FileStream and passed it to the SftpClient. It created the file and data successfully. It seams that it doesn't like MemoryStream for some reason.
Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to get it to work with MemoryStream and changed to to write a file and then read and upload that file.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] CustomerIds[] CustomerIds)
{
    try
    {
        if(CustomerIds.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("No customer ids passed in post body.");
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(sshKeyLocation))
        {
            throw new Exception("Missing ssh file.");
        }

        if(!Directory.Exists(localDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(localDirectory);
        }

        var customerAddresses = _repository.GetPrimaryAddress(CustomerIds.Select(c => c.Id))
            .Select(p => new
            {
                p.Customer.Name,
                p.Customer.AlternateName,
                p.City,
                p.StateProvince
            }
        );

        if (customerAddresses == null || !customerAddresses.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception("No customer addresses found for selected customers.");
        }

        var fileName = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(dateFromat) + destinationFileName;
        var localFilePath = Path.Combine(localDirectory, fileName);

        CreateFile(customerAddresses, localFilePath);
        UploadFile(localFilePath, fileName);
                   
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        logger.Error(error, error.Message);
        throw error;
    }
}

private void CreateFile(IEnumerable<object> customerAddresses, string filePath)
{
    using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(streamWriter))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(customerAddresses);
    }
}

private void UploadFile(string localFilePath, string destinationFileName)
{
    var connectionInfo = new PrivateKeyConnectionInfo(address,
        username,
        new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyLocation)
    );

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.ChangeDirectory(serverDirectory);
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, destinationFileName);
    }
}
```

I've run out of time to continue trying to upload using the MemoryStream and will just have to use this solution. Disappointed I couldn't get it to work.